# Problem about exporting the project

Tags: qgis, export, pdf

I'm working on a project using QGIS. I have 3 layers in the project, city boarder, the location of the natural monuments, and a layer as background card. I am going to have these three layers in my project, and I want to have the photos of 129 natural monuments as a row at the corner of layout. When I try to export the project as a PDF documents, it doesn't allow to continue the process. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: May be related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40919/qgis-exporting-huge-svg   If the dataset is large try using Save as Image instead of Print Composer function.

Comment: What error message do you get (if any)? Have you tried exporting a PDF __without__ the 129 images?

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried exporting something with potentially that much visual data in it from QGIS, but it sounds like it's failing due to the inclusion of the 129 photos (I can only guess as to the total size of them) and you need to separate rendering the corner section of the layout, where those photos reside, from the rest of the map. Try removing those 129 photos from your layout, exporting the layout to JPEG or some other image format, then add the photos to the image in a dedicated image manipulation program like GIMP or Photoshop and render your final output from there.