# Lines on SVG export from QGIS are rasterized

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-3, svg, vector-layer

I'm working with QGIS 3.0.2-Girona on Windows 7 64bits. I have a lot of roads on a large map (30 x 40 km approximately). I am trying to export them into vectorial format to print a map. However, the lines are rasterized and I have to make a very huge zoom (1:4000 in EPSG:2154, Lambert 93). Is it because there are too many elements?

I've seen [QGIS exporting huge SVG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40919/qgis-exporting-huge-svg) and have tried printing to pdf but obviously, it got rasterized. I will try to find a ubuntu 64 or to run it on a VM.

Is there any other suggestion? Is this a bug from Qt libs as suggested on some posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a VM with Ubuntu 17.10 64 bits and QGIS 2.18, I was able to export, through Composer panel, **PDF and SVG** vectorial files.